# Retrofit2 authentication key to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit2

I need to use the retrofit for consuming firebase json with authentication. I use code by https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-manage-request-headers-in-okhttp-interceptor

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
@Override
public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();

    // Request customization: add request headers
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", "auth-value"); // <-- this is the important line

    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
});

OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
```

For sure. What auth-value key from firebase console do i use please ?

Comment: so can I assume from your comments in the answer that you are not using Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per official firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth):

> To retrieve an access token you need to use a service account. Please see the guide for using Google Service Accounts. You can create a service account credential in your Firebase project from the Service Accounts section of the Firebase console.

```
GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("service_account.json"));
GoogleCredential scoped = googleCred.createScoped(
    Arrays.asList(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    )
);
scoped.refreshToken();
String token = scoped.getAccessToken();
```

**Using the access token**

> The Database REST API accepts access_token= on the query string or header Authorization: Bearer  to authenticate a request with a service account.

Comment: Thank you for help. I can't figure out retrofit read json of firebase node with rules auth != null. My final goal is but testing of notification from an android device to other android device. There i do not need the service account credential, there is enough Legacy Server key from setting CLOUD MESSAGING FirebaseConsole.

Comment: @eurosecom did this work for you? This is tagged with Android, and for this to work you'd have to store the json in the raw folder, which is not such a great idea if security is something you care about

Comment: @Chrisko I do not use Retrofit2 to consume Firebase Database. I use Firebase database API. Do you have better solving ?

Comment: @eurosecom why you should save some json in raw folder? What are you talking about?

Comment: @Divers What json are you talking about ? I have answered to Chrisko that I do not use Retrofit2 to consume Firebase database.

Comment: @Divers when you setup a project in Firebase, a JSON is generated for you which contains API keys, SHA checksums, and other data. You solution attempts to read that file. In the three years I've been developing in Android, every time I need to put a file such as a JSON I put it there. Perhaps my knowledge is somewhat obsolete. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Chisko it's not my solution, it's copy-paste from official documentation (btw, it's link on it in my answer). And am sure that they use info from your APK signature in order to verify you app in consumption with API keys, nothing insecure here, it's normal solution for all stuff similar on that.